# Switch / Case issue

Tags: c

For C language, I know I'm close, but for for any character inputted, the printout is "Consonant". What is wrong with my switch case statement. Will I need `if` statements?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char name;
    printf("Enter a character: ");
    scanf_s("%c", &name);

    switch (name)
    {
    case 'a':
        printf("Vowel");
        break;
    case 'e':
        printf("Vowel");
        break;
    case 'i':
        printf("Vowel");
        break;
    case 'o':
        printf("Vowel");
        break;
    case'u':
        printf("Vowel");
        break;
    case 'y':
        printf("Sometimes");
        break;
    default:
        printf("Consonant");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you entering uppercase characters? Have you tried a debugger?

Comment: the output in cmd asks a question "Enter a character:". so when any character is entered, the next line is printed with "Consonant". If I remove the default part from code, then there is no output printed after entering a character.

Comment: Surely step 1 is print the value of `name` so you can see what you're playing with?

Comment: It actually works fine, show what you are entering. You are not including the quotes (e.g. `'a'`) are you?

Comment: Hmm... there is no fall-through from default at the end, is there some other reason I'm missing? (just curious, not critical)

Comment: i'm using run>>CMD to run this program. running from visual studio makes it close window after inputting (hard to see the output). So i could be entering 342342324 or or xyz, any input, the next line output is always consonant

Comment: `3` goes to `default`. likewise `x`.

Comment: where are you really checking the input?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that the Microsoft page for [`scanf_s()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx) says:

> In the case of characters, a single character may be read as follows:
>
> ```
> char c;
>
> scanf_s("%c", &c, 1);
> ```

Your `scanf_s()` call is failing, but you are not checking the result, so you don't know that.

***ALWAYS*** check the result of input functions!

And make sure you've read the manual page for functions you're using.

It's probably also a good idea to use `" %c"` as the format string to skip white space.  However, that's a refinement for later.

---

You don't have a `break;` after the code in the `default:` case label.  That's not a good idea.

You can use:

```
if (scanf_s("%c", &name, 1) == 1)
{
    switch (name)
    {
    case 'a':
    case 'e':
    case 'i':
    case 'o':
    case 'u':
        printf("Vowel\n");
        break;
    case 'y':
        printf("Sometimes\n");
        break;
    default:
        printf("Consonant\n");
        break;
    }
}
else
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read a character\n");
```

Note that all upper-case letters, punctuation, white space and control characters are deemed to be consonants.  That's not entirely accurate.

Comment: thank you Jonathan! that helped, it was the ,1 within the scan_f line. also thanks for the additional suggestion regarding having case a, e, i, o , u followed by printf("Vowel\n"). added break too.

Comment: *it was the ,1 within the scan_f line* All the stuff in bold and italics and explanation on good practices conveniently ignored! smh